# SQL calc percent with independent subquery? union?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, union

I've an query to get defective parts and additionally I need to calculate the percent value to all produced parts over a timespan.

I'm an SQL noob, and I get not working solution. I have these two working querys and i want to combine them to calculate percent over the number of produced pieces.

I try with an easy subselect in the query. But then he is only calculating the number of pieces of the shifts the contain the defective parts. I dont get the sum of pieces over the whole timespan. So I want to combine these two querys.

After this I try join and union but I only get error messages.

I shortend and remane the shown querys to make them more understandable.

(Oracle 11gR2)

Query to get the Parts

```
SELECT Production.LineName, Names.DescDefect, Sum(Errors.Rework)
FROM Production, Batchdata, Errors, Names, ShiftData, Shifts
WHERE ...=... and ShiftData.Date=...
GROUP Production.Line, Names.DescDefect
HAVING (Production.LineNumber Like '700_')
ORDER BY ...
```

Result linke this:

```
LineName   DescDefect  Sum(Errors.Rework)
Line1      Defect1     10
Line1      Defect3     2
Line3      Defect12    5
Line3      Defect53    5
```

Query for the number of parts:

```
SELECT Production.LineName, Sum(Batchdata.Produced)
FROM Production, Batchdata
WHERE ...=... AND ((Production.LineNumber Like '700_') AND (ShiftData.Date=...))
GROUP BY Production.LineName
```

Result:

```
LineName   Sum(Batchdata.Produced)
Line1      500
Line3      700
```

What I want:

```
LineName   DescDefect  Sum(Errors.Rework)   percent
Line1      Defect1     10                   2
Line1      Defect3     2                    0,4
Line3      Defect12    5                    0,7
Line3      Defect53    5                    0,7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery within `select` taking part counts from a view(`with clause`)

```
WITH batchd AS
      (SELECT Production.LineName LineName,
              Sum(Batchdata.Produced) no_of_parts
       FROM Production,
            Batchdata WHERE ...=...
       AND ((Production.LineNumber LIKE '700_')
            AND (ShiftData.Date=...))
       GROUP BY Production.LineName )
    SELECT Production.LineName,
           Names.DescDefect,
           Sum(Errors.Rework),
           (Sum(Errors.Rework) /
              (SELECT no_of_parts
               FROM batchd b
               WHERE b.LineName = Production.LineName)) * 100 percent
    FROM Production,
         Batchdata,
         Errors,
         NAMES,
         ShiftData,
         Shifts WHERE ...=...
    AND ShiftData.Date=...
    GROUP Production.Line,
          Names.DescDefect
    HAVING (Production.LineNumber LIKE '700_')
    ORDER BY ...
```